# How do I create a superclass that extends AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android

I have to extend the android class android.os.AsyncTask (Params, Progress, Result). I have to add new methods and class variables without setting (Params, Progress, Result) in the superclass, as types will be defined by its children.

```
                 AsyncTask <Params, Progress, Result>
                               |
               My superclass <Params, Progress, Result>
                               |
                           ┌───┴───────────────┬───────────────────┐
                           |                   |                   |
         Child1 <Integer, Void, Integer>       |                   |
                                               |                   |
                            Child2 <JSONObject, Void, Integer>     |
                                                                   |
                                               Child3 <String, Void, Integer>
```

How do I implement this?

Comment: The same way you inherit any other class.  What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inherit generic classes the same way you inherit regular classes.

The inherited class can specify concrete types for the type parameters, or its own generic type arguments.

```
public abstract class CustomAsyncTask <Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask <Params, Progress, Result>
```